# Pressure in a 2D Ideal Gas simulation

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas

I am currently creating a 2D ideal gas simulator whereby the user can determine three of the four variables (P, V, n, T) and the gas would adjust accordingly.

I was wondering how I could calculate the pressure within this simulation. I was struggling with how to approach this problem considering how I am attempting to model a 3d scenario in 2d.

Comment: I think how you would approach this is a bit dependent on the problem you want to translate into 2D. Do you have a specific geometry and density/temperature structure in the third dimension in mind? Because usually 2D-pressure is a quantity that is proportional to column density instead of volume density, garnered with numerical prefactors that come from integrating the density/temperature profile in the third direction.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to make this relatively simple. I'm going to make the all of the particles equal mass, and temperature equal to the square of the particle speed... I hope this answers your question.

Comment: So do you have particles or a continuum? I'm confused. Pressure and temperature are only evolvable in a continuum theory.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape he has particles. However, you can extract pressure.  He is trying  to make a "molecular dynamics" simulation with classical particles (see the animation here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases)  and he is asking how to extract the pressure from such a kinetic simulation. See e.g. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01014270

Answer (score -1):

since the gas is a 2D one, you most start using
pA=Nm*(mean square velocity)/2

A=area (which is the 2D-volume, indicated in your question as V)
N= # of molecules enclosed in A ( 2D- volume)
hence 
n=N/A

then, the temperature can be estimated using
pA=NkT
where k is Boltzmann constant